How to interpert hwlat trace results on an ARM Cortex-A7?
I’m working with an STM32MP157D-DK1, trying to use the hwlat tracer for the board's arm Cortex-A7 CPU, to check for typical hardware latency.
The following attempt was made to use the hwlat tracer on the board:
# mount -t debugfs debugfs /sys/kernel/debug
# mount -t tracefs nodev /sys/kernel/tracing
# cd /sys/kernel/tracing
# cat hwlat_detector/window
1000000
# cat hwlat_detector/width
900000
# cat tracing_thresh
0
# cat tracing_max_latency
0
# cat tracing_cpumask
3
# cat hwlat_detector/mode
none [round-robin] per-cpu
# cat tracing_on
0
# cat current_tracer
nop
# echo hwlat > current_tracer

Assigning # echo hwlat > current_tracer would set tracing_thresh to 10, so:
# echo 0 > tracing_thresh
# cat tracing_thresh
0
# echo 1 > tracing_on
# sleep 1800
# cat trace


# tracer: hwlat
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 46/46   #P:2
#
#                                _-----=> irqs-off/BH-disabled
#                               / _----=> need-resched
#                              | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                              || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                              ||| / _-=> migrate-disable
#                              |||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID     CPU#  |||||  TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |         |   |||||     |         |
           <...>-159     [001] d....   240.855853: #1     inner/outer(us):    0/2     ts:946699046.769930071 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....   241.871956: #2     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699047.786034280 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   242.891945: #3     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699048.806022489 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....   243.911906: #4     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699049.825984865 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   246.971967: #5     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699052.886044616 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....   252.071924: #6     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699057.986000660 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   257.171915: #7     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699063.085992329 count:1
           <...>-159     [000] d....   272.471929: #8     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699078.386005920 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   273.491923: #9     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699079.406001504 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   277.571906: #10    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699083.485984589 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....   278.591918: #11    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699084.505996048 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   318.371905: #12    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699124.285982817 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   346.931903: #13    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699152.845980372 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   393.851943: #14    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699199.766020728 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   420.371906: #15    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699226.285984865 count:1
           <...>-159     [001] d....   487.691904: #16    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699293.605983314 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   614.171939: #17    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699420.086017333 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   646.811933: #18    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699452.726012015 count:1
           <...>-159     [001] d....   650.891904: #19    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699456.805984600 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   705.971922: #20    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699511.886000877 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   708.011907: #21    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699513.925987669 count:1
           <...>-159     [001] d....   763.091907: #22    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699569.005986862 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   824.291904: #23    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699630.205985225 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   893.651899: #24    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699699.565979716 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   895.691904: #25    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699701.605985717 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   912.011931: #26    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699717.926011266 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....   913.031903: #27    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699718.945983725 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   930.371903: #28    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699736.285984275 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....   934.451904: #29    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699740.365986111 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1034.411903: #30    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699840.325984200 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....  1049.711894: #31    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946699855.625976207 count:1
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1211.891897: #32    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700017.805979076 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1222.091906: #33    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700028.005987831 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1336.331903: #34    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700142.245984969 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1338.371900: #35    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700144.285983803 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1356.731931: #36    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700162.646014437 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1477.091900: #37    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700283.005983161 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....  1514.831892: #38    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700320.745975929 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1530.131903: #39    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700336.045985853 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....  1533.191895: #40    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700339.105978979 count:1
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1534.211901: #41    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700340.125985563 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....  1571.951896: #42    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700377.865979289 count:2
           <...>-159     [000] d....  1639.271892: #43    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700445.185976197 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1664.771895: #44    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700470.685979917 count:2
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1679.051899: #45    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700484.965983799 count:1
           <...>-159     [001] d....  1768.811900: #46    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946700574.725985300 count:2


After a half an hour sleep, this is what is logged to file trace. I'm trying to understand this result. Trying to take assistance in Steven Rosetedt's walkthrough of the hwlat tracer output.
In another 20 minutes test I ran with similar conditions, there also appeared a line where numerous encounters of a 3 millisecond latency occurred, rather than the frequent 0, 1 or 2 microsec. It looks like this (see #16's count):
# tracer: hwlat
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 20/20   #P:2
#
#                                _-----=> irqs-off/BH-disabled
#                               / _----=> need-resched
#                              | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                              || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                              ||| / _-=> migrate-disable
#                              |||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID     CPU#  |||||  TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |         |   |||||     |         |
           <...>-169     [001] d....   328.696323: #1     inner/outer(us):    0/2     ts:946685131.612004155 count:2
           <...>-169     [000] d....   329.711962: #2     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685132.627644489 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....   332.771947: #3     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685135.687627240 count:2
           <...>-169     [000] d....   333.791924: #4     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685136.707605282 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....   334.811973: #5     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685137.727653991 count:2
           <...>-169     [000] d....   335.831926: #6     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685138.747608742 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....   336.851921: #7     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685139.767602242 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....   345.011927: #8     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685147.927608371 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....   365.411950: #9     inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685168.327631214 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....   455.171927: #10    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685258.087609424 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....   471.491916: #11    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685274.407599140 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....   616.331919: #12    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685419.247601959 count:2
           <...>-169     [000] d....   805.031908: #13    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946685607.947590632 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....  1285.451914: #14    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946686088.367599861 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....  1324.211913: #15    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946686127.127599213 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....  1540.451925: #16    inner/outer(us):    1/3     ts:946686344.024041733 count:457
           <...>-169     [000] d....  1541.471970: #17    inner/outer(us):    0/2     ts:946686344.387656150 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....  1546.571943: #18    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946686349.487628111 count:2
           <...>-169     [000] d....  1547.591934: #19    inner/outer(us):    0/2     ts:946686350.507622153 count:2
           <...>-169     [001] d....  1548.611929: #20    inner/outer(us):    0/1     ts:946686351.527615528 count:2


Since then I have made more half an hour/whole hour tests, their results are similar to those of the first log file shown.
Please note that according to the hardware latency detector documentation :

The tracer hwlat_detector is a special purpose tracer that is used to
detect large system latencies induced by the behavior of certain
underlying hardware or firmware, independent of Linux itself. The code
was developed originally to detect SMIs (System Management Interrupts)
on x86 systems, however there is nothing x86 specific about this
patchset.

I'm assuming that the reasons that x86 processors need SMIs (temperature management, ...) are inevitably present on arm cores too.
How should these results be interpreted? 
Hardware latency from the Cortex-A7 doesn't exceed 3 microseconds?
Is there something wrong with what I’m doing?
